# Are attribute specifiers any useful in function definitions?

Tags: c++, attributes, c++17

I wonder if I should omit adding the attribute specifiers to header files/function definitions. Is it a good practice to write them out even there? Do they do any good? Consider this example:

```
// Header file
static void e_nullptr_dereference();

// Cpp file
[[noreturn, gnu::cold]] void EfficiencyPlotsModule::e_nullptr_dereference()
{
   throw std::runtime_error("Trying to deference a nullptr in the module list. This is not supported.");
}
```

Is there any point of indicating the compiler-helper attributes in the definition too? Does it help the compiler or is it considered to be more clean code:

```
[[noreturn, gnu::cold]] static void e_nullptr_dereference();
```

How about template functions?

```
// Header file
class MyClass
{
  (...)

  template <MyClass::ClassEnum scenario = MyClass::someScenario>
  void  memberFunction();
}

(...)

extern template void MyClass::memberFunction<MyClass::SomeScenario>();

// Cpp file
template void MyClass::memberFunction<MyClass::someScenario>();

(...)

template <MyClass::ClassEnum someScenario>
[[gnu::hot]] void MyClass::memberFunction()
{
}
```

Should I list the attributes at the other occurences too?

My guess would be that the compiler optimizes the occurences of the calls of the marked function in other functions: for example cold functions won't get precached at branching points. For the template functions my guess would be that it is necesarry to add the attributes to the template specification declaration (even if it is `extern`, for example: `extern [[gnu::hot]] template void MyClass::memberFunction<MyClass::SomeScenario>();`). Am I right?

Comment: It depends on the specifier. Some of them just describe how the function itself should be compiled; others, how calls to it should be compiled.

Comment: For `noreturn`, it is an error if this attribute is not specified in the first declaration.